# Can't install Beamer Theme on Manjaro Linux

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I have an problem with latex.
I want to use this beamertheme: https://github.com/matze/mtheme 
I followed the installation guide, but it didn't worked.
I get an error:
'''

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty)))
! LaTeX Error: File `beamerthememetropolis.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.8 \usetheme{metropolis}
^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
19669 strings out of 478353
374331 string characters out of 5854635
645811 words of memory out of 5000000
37459 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
404035 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
99i,0n,104p,444b,286s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

'''
I am on Manjaro and using Texmaker.
I tried

```
'kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME'
```

and got

```
'/home/julian/texmf'
```

this Directory didn't existed yet, what I taught was strange. I made the directory and copied the .sty files in it. I also tried it with the structure:
/home/julian/textmf/tex/latex and then copied this file. Also didn't worked. Also copied the files in /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/ The file from the error message has also a copy in this folder.

Has anyone a hint for me? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of manually installing this theme, you could use the one included in your tex installation. For vanilla texlive, you can install it via `tlmgr install beamertheme-metropolis`